# call docker's host machine from docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I have an nginx server with a static html file that is served within docker.

The `Dockerfile` looks like the following:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx nodejs

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy a configuration file from the current directory
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

ADD Front-Dev/v2/desktop /usr/share/nginx/html/
ADD Front-Dev/v2/desktop /var/www/html/

# Append "daemon off;" to the beginning of the configuration
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Set the default command to execute
# when creating a new container
CMD service nginx start
```

The Docker container is executed by the following command: `sudo docker run -p 9002:9000 pitstop-nginx`

In parallel on Docker's host there is executed server with APIs. This server works without Docker and uses port 9002.

In the static page that is located in Docker JS trying to call server API `/api/auth/login` and due to the request is made inside the docker I obtained  502 error.

How can I fix it? Can you explain me what should I modify in Docker so that  requests from Docker go to Docker host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot run both docker host API server & the container on host port 9002. Change the docker run to -

   `sudo docker run -p 9003:9000 pitstop-nginx`
2. Get the host machine private IP by using `ipconfig` or `ifconfig`.
3. Add a hostname to the private IP which docker container can understand(10.100.101.108 - My host private IP) -

   `sudo docker run --add-host="my-host-machine:10.100.101.108" -p 9003:9000 pitstop-nginx`

(Use variables if Docker host IP is subject to change)

4. Your host machine is reachable with a hostname now -

   ```
   root@721508a294ad:/# ping my-host-machine 
   PING my-host-machine (10.100.101.108) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from my-host-machine (10.100.101.108): icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=0.865 ms
   ```
5. Use `proxy pass` in Nginx to redirect all the API request to you host machine -

   ```
   location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://my-host-machine:9002/;
   }
   ```

PS - This is a quick fix to this problem. However, For long run I will suggest you to integrate both setups(host & container) into a single compose file to get rid of such issues.